# Does quadratic convergence of Newton's method require a continuous second derivative?

Tags: continuity, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, newton-raphson

I read a part of the [wikipedia page of Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#:%7E:text=Equation%20(6)%20shows%20that%20the%20order%20of%20convergence%20is%20at%20least%20quadratic%20if%20the%20following%20conditions%20are%20satisfied%3A)
where it is shown that the order of convergence for Newton's method of finding a root is quadratic, i.e.
$$
|\varepsilon_{n+1}| = \dfrac{f''(\xi_n)}{2|f'(x_n)|} \cdot \varepsilon_n^2 \quad ,
$$
where $\varepsilon_n = \alpha - x_n$, $\alpha$ is the root, $x_n$ is the "nth guess" and $\xi_n$ is in between $x_n$ and $\alpha$. It is stated that the equation shows that

> ...the order of convergence is at least quadratic if the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. $f'(x) \neq 0$; for all $x \in I$ where $I$ is the interval $[\alpha - r, \alpha + r]$ for some $r \geq |\alpha - x_0|$;
> 2. $f''(x)$ is continuous, for all $x \in I$;
> 3. $x_0$ is *sufficiently* close to the root $\alpha$.
>
> The term *sufficiently* close in this context means the following:
> a. Taylor approximation is accurate enough such that we can ignore higher order terms;
> b. $\dfrac{1}{2} \left| \dfrac{f''(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \right| < C\left| \dfrac{f''(\alpha)}{f'(\alpha)} \right|$ for some $C < \infty$;
> c. $C \left | \dfrac{f''(\alpha)}{f'(\alpha)} \right | \varepsilon_n < 1$,
> for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n \geq 0$ and $C$ satisfying condition b.

I wonder if condition 2. is required and in that case why?

---

The only hint at why this continuity of the second derivative is required is that the article claims that it ensures Taylor's theorem can be applied to write $f(x_n)$ as a Taylor series of order $1$ with the remainder in Lagrange form. However, the [wikipedia page on Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) does not require the second derivative be continuous, only that $f$ is $2$-times differentiable and some other conditions. So I don't understand where the requirement of a continuous second derivative may come from.

Comment: One clarification. The quadratic convergence doesn't need anything, not even existence of derivative except for one point. It can just happen by coincidence for a particular function. You are talking about a sufficient condition. So, the question should rather be if continuous second derivative is required by that proof of a sufficient condition. It is used for the existence of the $\xi$ in the remainder of the Taylor expansion.

Comment: @user85667 Oh, ok. So why is continuity of the second derivative required for the existence of $\xi$ in the remainder of the Taylor expansion? I don't see that this is part of Taylor's theorem.

Comment: I think that continuity of the second derivative is used in the "sufficiently close" bit of the proof on the Wikipedia page for Newton's method. So, it's not requiring it to use Taylor's theorem, but it implicitly uses it to argue that the constant C is finite. For completeness, you might include that theorem in your question.

Comment: @McGonald Ha! Your question in the comment suffers the same imprecision. The existence of the $\xi$ doesn't require the continuity of the second derivative. It is again a sufficient condition. The continuity of the second derivative is sufficient to ensure the existence of the $\xi$. That is the [Taylor theorem with Lagrange form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)

Comment: @user85667 Yes that was the version of Taylor's theorem I was referring to. As far as I can see it does not require that the second derivative is continuous for $\xi$ to exist, $\xi$ will exist as long as the second derivative exist and the other conditions are met?

Comment: @ShawSa Ok, I will include that part in my question.

Comment: @McGonald Yes, indeed, you can still get the $\xi$ without the continuity of $f''$.

Comment: Ah, there is another part that maybe they are using the continuity of $f''$. It might be to ensure a bound on the quotients $|f''|/|f'|$. We don't want these going to infinity for $f''$ becoming large near $\alpha$. We need some constant such that the next error is bounded by that constant times the square of the previous error. As with the existence of $\xi$, one can put weaker conditions to ensure this bound.

Comment: @user85667 Hmm yes that may be true, I was also considering something like that but can't help but feel that the quotient is finite no matter if $f''$ is continuous or not and that that's what is important. Don't really see why we would worry about a limit here?

Comment: @user85667 But you are probably right that I misunderstood the conditions as necessary when they are really sufficient, thanks for that!

Comment: Well, you can have existence of second derivative without this being bounded. We do need to ensure a constant bound on the $|f''|/|f|$ to finish that argument that $|e_{n+1}|/|e_n|^2$ is bounded by a constant, to verify the definition of [quadratic convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#Convergence_speed_for_iterative_methods).

Comment: Sure, but $|f''(\xi_n)|/|f'(x_n)|$ is bounded as long as $f''(\xi_n)/f'(x_n)$ is defined, no need for $f''$ to be continuous. But it may be as you already said, that they are not really stating necessary conditions here.

Comment: You have all answers in http://www.numdam.org/item/NAM_1869_2_8__17_0.pdf